# SQL Excluding all possibilities contained in lists when making assignments

Tags: sql, postgresql

Say I have this table:

```
col1   col2    col3
1      Amy    [Jessica, Laura, Joe]
1     Jessica [Jessica, Laura, Joe]
2     Steve   [Amy, Mike]
2      Amy    [Amy, Mike]
```

For each number in col1, I want to select a person in col2 (ex. for 1 I want to select Amy or Jessica). However, any of the people in the corresponding list in col3 should not be selected (Jessica). How can I write a query that results in the following table? I've never worked with lists in SQL before.

```
id  person
1    Amy
2    Steve
```

Comment: What is the data type of `col3`?

Answer (score 1):

Presumably, the "list" in `col3` is an array.  If so:

```
select t.*
from t
where col2 <> all (col3);
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=c45af3d67f1eef37f89fa5e8bb01c169) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Thanks! How can I check the data type of col3?

Comment: @Hanna . . . You can look at the definition of the table.

Comment: Is there a SQL query that I have to write to get the definition of the table? I don't know how to do this.

Comment: @Hanna . . . You can use the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` view.